# windows phone error occured while finding the resource dictionary

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dictionary

So, i am creating universal windows phone app.I am trying to change the color of clicked item in pivot header panel .I have added the Styling.axml file  in windows phone project with this syntax:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FacilityAppWindowsPhone">

    <Style x:Key="CustomPivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleContentControlStyle}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in App.xaml file in Shared project i am trying to add this piece of code

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dictionary">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styling.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

But i am getting error "En error occured while finding the resource dictionary "Styling.axml".

Comment: is your styling.xaml file in the root folder? and try removing x:Key="Dictionary" from ResourceDictionary tag

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/bdlddz.png ...this is structure of the project..And when i try to remove the key it says "Each dictionary must have and associated key"

Comment: are you creating a UNIVERSAL APPLICATION or just WINDOWS PHONE 8.1 APPLICATION ? and this Styling.xaml ResourceDictionary is used in both applications or just in windows phone app?

Comment: I am making universal application(but for now i work only with phone version)..Its used just in Windows phone app..Have something on your mind?

Comment: Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445015/separate-resourcedictionary-for-each-project-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i abandoned this approach and this is how i solved it in the code:
In .xaml file add this property in the Pivot tag : SelectionChanged="MyPivot_SelectionChanged"

And than in the code:

```
 private void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender,    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (PivotItem pivotItem in MyPivot.Items)
            {
                if (pivotItem == MyPivot.Items[MyPivot.SelectedIndex])
                {
                    //selected
                   ((TextBlock)pivotItem.Header).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255,31, 93, 184));
                }
                else
                {
                     // not selected
                    ((TextBlock)pivotItem.Header).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255,109, 162, 240 ));
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference a dictionary like this for a universal app (assuming the dictionary is in the shared project):

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///MyUniversaldResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
```

I recently blogged about this if you want a bit more detail:
[Accessing Resources in a Universal App](http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=614)